# how to run a non-ROS software in ubuntu after i downloaded from github?

Tags: ros, 3rd-party-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I would like to run a software in Ubuntu called [carDetect](https://github.com/skandhurkat/CarDetect) and this application i found it in GitHub. so I already downloaded this software from GitHub  to my desktop, and I want to run it in Ubuntu
How can i run this application after i downloaded to Ubuntu?

Thank you for your help**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217092/how-to-run-a-non-ros-software-in-ubuntu-after-i-downloaded-from-github-?/) by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The software you refer to doesn't seem like a ROS package. So you can just follow the package's instruction to (build if necessary and) run it.

If you're asking how to run the software as a ROS package, I can think of some levels of tasks depending on what part of ROS you want to utilize:

- a. You just want to build the software via ROS' build system (catkin). Then "catkin-ize" it (making software with catkin-compatible). There's actually no document AFAIK that specifically talks about this task, but you may start from [catkin's tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials). Typically this task requires adding `package.xml` and modifying `CMakeLists.txt` at minimum.
- b. You want to utilize ROS commandline to access your package or executables in your package (example commands are below). To this you don't need extra tasks except for a.

  ```
    roscd your_pkg 
    rosrun your_pkg your_exec
  ```
- c. If you want to run executables as ROS nodes, you need to change codes in addition to what was necessary in a and b. Again I don't think there are any documents that teach you how to turn non-ROS programs to ROS nodes, so I can only suggest you to go through some of existing tutorials (maybe [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes), [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)) to get ideas.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on 2015-09-06**:
I truly appreciate your help
Would you please create the package in ros and send it to me ( assamali5@gmail.com)
I tried many times and I still go through problem to create it in ROS because I don't have strong experience
And I promise you I will never forget what you do for me
God bless You